# Problem with addEventListener inside module

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects, addeventlistener

I'm having problem with addEventListener inside modul. I want to change propety of object by addEventListner inside class, so i wrote a simple example what i mean. What to do to make it work ?

```
import Person from './new.js'

const citizen = new Person();
citizen.changeName();
console.log(citizen.name); // expect to see event.traget, see null
```

```
export class Person{
    constructor(){
        this.name = null ;
    }

    changeName(){
        document.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            this.name = event.target;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `changeName` adds a click listener, it doesn't run the click listener - only the user can do that. Wait for the user to click before examining the name.

Comment: Ok, Is there any function teling wait for listner ? I mean how to write this to make it work ?

Comment: I guess you could pass a callback, or promisify `changeName` and then `await` the call of it